# QGIS / PostgreSQL : label a layer with the value from an other layer linked through a foreign key

Tags: qgis, postgresql, labeling

I have 2 PostGIS layers linked through a foreign key.

**Layer 1** : Primary key
**Layer 2** : Primary key / *Foreign key*

I want to label the Layer 1 with the value of an attribute of Layer 2 through his foreign key.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is possible,
you can use an expression like this, either in the label or as a virtual field:

```
attribute( 
 get_feature( 'table','ne_id', "ne_id" ),
 'name')
```

In this example i used a layer named **"table"** containing natural earth countries data and the label expression is inside the corresponding geometries, a layer I loaded with only geometries and the **"ne_id"** field (your foreign key)

Comment: Yes ! It works ! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @User Then please accept the answer