# Create a line connecting 2 features from layers linked by a foreign key with QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have 2 PostGIS layers linked through a foreign key.

**Layer 1** : Primary key
**Layer 2** : Primary key / *Foreign key*

I want to create a *line connecting* the 2 features that are linked by a foreign key.

I think I need to use *make-line* function but I don't know how to write it.

I asked a similar question on post : [QGIS / PostgreSQL : label a layer with the value from an other layer linked through a foreign key](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/402967/qgis-postgresql-label-a-layer-with-the-value-from-an-other-layer-linked-thro) but for labeling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of a virtual layer.

Go to `Layer/ Add layer/ add-edit virtual layer` and enter the following query. Feel free to add as many field as you want from the two layers.

```sql
SELECT a.id, b.id, makeline(a.geometry, b.geometry) as geometry
FROM myFirstLayer a
 JOIN mySecondLayer b
 ON a.primary_key = b.foreign_key
```

Comment: Great, it works ! Thank you. Do you think it is possible to do the same but directly in Layer Style ?

Comment: I have tried somethink like that (the 2 layers are point type layers) but it doesn't work : make_line(
  geometry(
 get_feature('fildo','idfildo', "idfildo")
 ) , 
 geometry(
 get_feature('devorage','idfildo', "idfildo")
)
)

Comment: it is certainly possible, but I will leave it to someone else to write the optimal answer for this case. Note that the geometry of the layer being rendered should be `$geometry` only

Answer (score 3):

To get the result with geometry generator using two point layer you need to use this expression on the parent layer symbology (your expression in comment was almost right, you just dont need to first get_feature as the expression generator evaluate feature by feature):

```
make_line ( $geometry , geometry( get_feature ( 'Child_layer_name' , 'Child_layer_foreign_key_field' ,  "Parent_layer_key field")))
```

Note that the Child_layer_foreign_key_field is between single quote while the Parent_layer_key field has double quote

Below is a more general illustration for polygon layer using the centroid  for starting point on parent layer and "Point_on _surface" for end point on child layer ; both layer are linked by the "KEY" field on PARENT layer and "FOREIGN_KEY" field on CHILD layer. The geometry generator expression become :

```
make_line(centroid($geometry), point_on_surface(geometry(get_feature('CHILD', 'FOREIGN_KEY', "KEY"))))
```

(this expression could easily be modified to use diferent way to generate the starting and end point or to generate starting and end point for line geometry)
[image]

Comment: This is what I need, but unfortunately it doesn't work. `make_line($geometry, geometry(get_feature('devorage','idfildo', "idfildo")))`. The script seems to be ok but returns "False"for the feature who suppose to be "True".

Comment: What do you mean by "returns "False"for the feature who suppose to be "True"", this should draw a line between 2 feature